# Link tracking -how is it done?

Tags: database-design, analytics, tracking, hyperlink

Say I want to track how many & which users on my site clicked the footer links.
There are 4 links: Terms, Privacy, Contact, Feedback. (This is an example. I need this for all links on my site. And i need to do it in house without using Google analytics or other packages as some data is highly confidential and cannot disclose it out to these companies). Platform is MySQL and PHP.

I assume it will be like this:
1) I have a lookup table for links

```
link_id, link, path
```

2) I have a lookup table for page text (for the actual words like Terms..)

```
text_id, text
```

3) I reference the text on the page for the 4 words (the `text_id`)
4) I reference the links on the page (`link_id`)

**Now i know how to do step 3, but i have no idea how to do step 4?**

5) Then once i get step 4 done then i need to write a php function which will capture the `user_id` and write the `user_id`, `link_id`, `datetime` to a link tracking table + the `activity_id` from the activity lookup table which is like `activity_id 6 = visit` link? **Is this valid?**

6) **Missing anything else?**

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to wrap the links in a little Javascript that does two things:

1) Fires off an ajax command, but does not need a response
2) Directs the browser to the link.

The ajax command requests a static resource with parameters, like "logThis.html?user=xxx&linkid=xxx&otherparm=xxxx"

These now appear in your apache logs.  Suck the apache logs into your data warehouse, filtering for the "logThis.html" lines and bob's your uncle.

Comment: Does it have to get into the apache log file or can i write direct into a user_log table in the database? This is real time analytic, so as soon as the user click a link, it will appear in his feeds and also get pushed out for analytics. if i do apache then into dw there will be a delay.

Comment: There is no AJAX involved in Google Analytics.

Comment: To avoid apache, make "logThis.html" into "logThis.php", which takes the entry and either A) inserts it right away, or B) saves it into a file for loading every 20-30 seconds in near real time.  A is easier to code and can be converted to B later if performance issues require it.